# Why do we need myisam spatial extension anyway?

Tags: mysql, myisam, spatial

If just to determine whether a point is within a rectangle,

What is wrong with this query?
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT
  TB.ID,
  TB.Latitude,
  TB.Longitude
FROM
  TableBusiness AS TB

WHERE
  -6.2317830813328 < TB.Latitude AND TB.Latitude < -6.1382169186672
AND TB.FoursquarePeopleCount >5   AND 106.72621691867 < TB.Longitude AND TB.Longitude <106.81978308133
LIMIT
  0, 20

It seems that normal index would do fine. After all TB.Latitude and TB.Longitude is indexed.

But then I want to do something more complicated like nearest neighbor search.

Then somebody says that even with spatial index I can't do that. I have to start with a small rectangle, find all points within that rectangle, and then see if I got 20 points, if not, make the rectangle bigger.

If I have to go through all that, why do I need spatial index?

So what's the point of having spatial index?